# Changing Default Directory for ArcCatalog Connect To Folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

When [connecting to a folder](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/using-folder-connections.htm#GUID-D7AC35CF-9057-46E2-93E7-E11069D64DF0) in Arccatalog, is it possible to change the directory that the **Connect To Folder** dialogue box defaults to?

It currently defaults to C:\Users\username

Comment: I don't know if you can change that, but did you know you can just type or paste a folder path into the ArcCatalog address bar and it will automatically create that as a new connected Folder? So no need to use the Connect To Folder dialog